# IAR EWARM (ICC) - Expression must have a constant value

Tags: c, pointers, icc, iar

I'm trying to compile the following C code using IAR EWARM but I'm getting three compilation errors (Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value). See below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t I2C_BusIdentifier;
typedef uint8_t I2C_SlaveAddress;

typedef enum {
    I2C_BUS_STATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0,
    I2C_BUS_STATE_GPIO_HARDWARE_READY,
    I2C_BUS_STATE_READY_TO_OPERATE,
} I2C_BusState;

typedef struct BUS_I2C_BUS_INSTANCE_TYPE {
    I2C_BusIdentifier BusIdentifer;                                         // 0 for I2C0, 1 for I2C1
    I2C_BusState CurrentState;                                              // bus status
} I2C_Bus; // I²C Bus Instance Type, I2C_BusInstanceType


typedef struct DEVICE_I2C_GENERIC {
    I2C_Bus* DeviceBusPointer;
    I2C_SlaveAddress DeviceAddress;
} I2C_Device;

// inherits from I2C_Device
typedef struct DEVICE_ADC123 {
    I2C_Device Device;
} ADC123_Device;

#define NUMBER_OF_I2C_PORTS   2

static I2C_Bus g_I2C_Bus[NUMBER_OF_I2C_PORTS] = {
    { 0, I2C_BUS_STATE_UNINITIALIZED, },
    { 1, I2C_BUS_STATE_UNINITIALIZED, },
};

I2C_Bus* const g_I2C_BusPtr_Port0 = &(g_I2C_Bus[0]);
I2C_Bus* const g_I2C_BusPtr_Port1 = &(g_I2C_Bus[1]);


const ADC123_Device g_Device_ADC123_U14 = {
    { g_I2C_BusPtr_Port0, 0xAE, }, // <--- Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value
};

const ADC123_Device g_Device_ADC123_U15 = {
    { g_I2C_BusPtr_Port1, 0x8A, }, // <--- Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value
};

const ADC123_Device g_Device_ADC123_U9 = {
    { g_I2C_BusPtr_Port1, 0xAA, }, // <--- Error[Pe028]: expression must have a constant value
};

#define NUMBER_OF_ADC123_DEVICES   3

const ADC123_Device* g_ADC123_Array[NUMBER_OF_ADC123_DEVICES] = {
    &g_Device_ADC123_U14,
    &g_Device_ADC123_U15,
    &g_Device_ADC123_U9,
};

int main(void)
{
    while(1);
}
```

However, everything compiles OK if I use the g_I2C_Bus addresses directly instead of through the g_I2C_BusPtr_PortX pointers:

```
const ADC123_Device g_Device_ADC123_U14 = {
    { &(g_I2C_Bus[0]), 0xAE, },
};

const ADC123_Device g_Device_ADC123_U15 = {
    { &(g_I2C_Bus[1]), 0x8A, },
};

const ADC123_Device g_Device_ADC123_U9 = {
    { &(g_I2C_Bus[1]), 0xAA, },
};
```

I want to use the const pointers (g_I2C_BusPtr_Port0, g_I2C_BusPtr_Port1) because they are extern'd in a .h file, whereas the array (g_I2C_Bus[]) will not be exposed globally but static in a specific .c file.

Why is the compuler unhappy about this when the definitions/values should be equivalent since they reference the same thing?

Comment: I don't think this is about guessing what errors you are getting, please be specific.

Answer (score 6):

This is a limitation with C language. Values of variables, like

```
int const a = 1;
```

cannot be used in constant expressions, like as initializers:

```
int b = a; /* Will not work */
```

Not even with `const` qualifier. Reasoning is that compiler cannot know values of variables, even if it would seem completely trivial. Variable with `const` is not *a constant* in C, it's only variable which cannot be changed by *you*.

Addresses of global variables are a different matter. Linker complete control where these variables are located, and can use the same information for initializers.

Work-around is to use preprocessor:

```
#define g_I2C_BusPtr_Port0 (&(g_I2C_Bus[0]))
```

Comment: He wants to keep `g_I2C_BusPtr_Port0` as a variable because it is used elsewhere; the workaround is just to write `&(g_I2C_Bus[0])` in the initializer list instead of `g_I2C_BusPtr_Port0` .

Answer (score 1):

In case it is not clear from the other answers already; the correct code organization is:

```
// stuff.h
//
extern I2C_Bus *const g_I2C_BusPtr_Port0;
extern I2C_Bus *const g_I2C_BusPtr_Port1;
```

and then:

```
// stuff.c
//
#include "stuff.h"

I2C_Bus* const g_I2C_BusPtr_Port0 = &g_I2C_Bus[0];
I2C_Bus* const g_I2C_BusPtr_Port1 = &g_I2C_Bus[1];

const ADC123_Device g_Device_ADC123_U14 = 
{ { &g_I2C_Bus[0], 0xAE } };
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Intializers for a static object must either be a constant expression or a string literal, if for example `ADC123_Device g_Device_ADC123_U14` was a automatic variable then there would be no error, for example if you declared it in `main`. We can see this by going to the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.8` Initialization which says:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be
>   constant expressions or string literals.

The reason why the second case works is that constant addresses are allowed, we can see this from `6.6` Constant expressions which says:

> More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant
>   expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following:

and includes the following bullet:

> - an address constant, or